# Looping and Saving Scatterplots in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of 2 columns and 3110 rows. The X column is a constant, where as the Y column changes each row. I am looking to create a loop that will generate a scatter plot for each row, and ultimately save the scatter plots onto my desktop.

The original code that I would use to create one scatter plot is:

```
X <- Abundances$s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis
Y <- Abundances$Gene1

plot(X, Y, main = "Species Vs Gene Expression", 
     xlab = "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", ylab = "Gene1",
     pch = 19, frame = FALSE)
```

So, the X variable is a specie name, and will stay constant. The Y variable is a gene name, and will change for each of the 3110 plots. I am using the percentage abundances for the gene expression and the specie's from another data frame called "Abundances".

A short snippet of my data looks like so, it has 2 columns, one column called Predictor, and one column called response:

```
Response <- c("ENSG00000000005.5",  "ENSG00000001167.10", "ENSG00000001617.7", "ENSG00000003393.10",  "ENSG00000004142.7")
Predictor <- c("s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis",  "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis",  "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis" )
```

If anyone could help me generate a loop that could create a scatter plot for each individual gene (on the y axis), against the specie on the X axis, and then immediately save these plots on my desktop, that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please make your example reproducible? I'm pretty confused by your data structure. Is all the data in one data frame? When you use `X <- s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis`, where does `s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis` come from? It would help a lot if you provided sample code / sample data that can be run in a new R session. `Response <- gene1, gene2, gene3,` isn't valid R syntax, so it doesn't help much. And if you mean `Response <- c(gene1, gene2, gene3)` it still doesn't help us much since we don't have `gene1`, `gene2`, and `gene3` defined.

Comment: `dput()` is a very useful command for sharing sample data. If you have a data frame `df`, then `dput(df[1:10, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of `df`. If you could use `dput()` on a small illustrative sample of data, that would help a lot.

Comment: Yes of course, I can try! 

`Response <- c("ENSG00000000005.5", 
"ENSG00000001167.10", "ENSG00000001617.7", "ENSG00000003393.10", 
"ENSG00000004142.7")
Predictor <- c("s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", 
"s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", 
"s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis", "s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis"
)`

I am pulling the % abundance's for both my response and my predictor from a different data set. 

So ultimately, it would be: 
`X <- Abundance$s__Coprobacillus_cateniformis, Y <- Abundances$'GeneID'`

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you! Please edit that detail into your question, rather than keeping it buried in comments. It would also help if the sample data had samples for 2 plots so that the looping can be illustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to test without a sample from `Abundances`, but I think this is on the right track. The key thing to note is that `$` doesn't work with strings, but `[[` does: `Abundances$Gene1` is the same as `Abundances[["Gene1"]]` is the same as `col = "Gene1"; Abundances[[col]]`.

```
for(i in seq_along(Response)) {
  png(filename = paste0("plot_", Response[i], ".png"))
  X <- Abundances[[Predictor[i]]]  
  Y <- Abundances[[Response[i]]]
  plot(X, Y, main = "Species Vs Gene Expression", 
       xlab = Response[i], ylab = Predictor[i],
       pch = 19, frame = FALSE)
  dev.off()
}
```

If you want the plots on your desktop, set that as the working directory or put the paste to your desktop as part of the filename.

Comment: Hey Gregor - I seem to have a lot of red X's in my R studio - suggesting that there are unmatched brackets, or expected commas after certain commands. I still ran the code, however, got no output... So I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I was missing the `)` for the `png()` command, it's fixed now. This is why it's difficult to help without a fully reproducible example. Without any sample from `Abundances` I can't run any of this code to debug it,..